# What is the outcome of the following reaction?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

The first step is clear to me, making an immine.
However how does the immine react again?
Perhaps it can be reacting with the carbonyl or alkene (to carbonyl over conjugation) I can't get to the target formula.

Comment: Iminium --> enamine (basic conditions, alpha proton to lose). The enamine acts as a nucleophile to add into the electrophile in 2.

Comment: Once you do the step mentioned above, start looking for _intramolecular_ reactions...

Comment: Look up Stork Enamine alkylation.